# Install Ubuntu on hard disk externally

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I want to install ubuntu on my other laptop.The Laptop wont allow me to boot from CD and i cant change the boot order. I dont have access to BIOS Settings (I am locked out of BIOS). I have an external hard disk reader.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to install an os on my laptop but it wont allow me to boot from CD for some reason. Is there any way i can install the OS on the hard drive via an other laptop and then put the drive in the original one

Comment: Can you boot via USB?

Comment: If you can't access the BIOS you won't be able to configure your computer to whats required to install Ubuntu. You have to explain what "Sony VAIO OTP" is exactly because my research on it is really helpful.  **( i.e. who is they )**

Comment: SONY has an OTP lock that i don't know how it triggers and to unlock it you need the key from sony. To give the keys, sony wants you to show them the proof of ownership. Now I don't have proof with me (I don't have the bill with me, I cant find it) and they wont unlock it.

Comment: @Bruno9979 . It does not support boot form USB.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be able to install Linux in one laptop, then move the hard drive to your locked laptop and it should boot and work but:

You need to perform a minimal install, so use the correct ISO. Ubuntu help forum has the instructions how to do that.

Next move the HD into your locked laptop. The installed Linux kernel is going to be generic, and it should boot into a single user text-mode only system which is going to give your the options to configure / access both the CD drive of your locked laptop and the laptop's network interface. From that point on you are going to be able to install a full Ubuntu system either from CD or via network.

Again, I would first do his much, and see if the OTP you are referring to allows booting a changed HD structure at all.

Comment: So i have to swap hard drives into my other laptop or can I install it by using hdd reader

Comment: Swap hard drives. If the two laptops are using compatible NIC hardware your are going to be in good shape and save some painful process of downloading drivers, burning them to CD, and installing them on your locked laptop. Use the path of least resistance. Be warned though, Linux has no control over the boot sequence so you are not going to be able to boot anything else but the hard drive - but once Linux takes control of the hardware you are going to have free access to all hardware.

Comment: I removed the windows recovery partition on the device and it asks to put a bootable disk in. But it wont boot from any of it just one old cd which has centos (i checked) but oddly boots into DR-DOS. Will try swapping hard drives.

Comment: You are not seem to follow: 1 - download Ubuntu minimal and burn it to CD, 2 - move the HD from your locked laptop into the other laptop, and boot that laptop with the Ubuntu CD, 3 - Install a minimal system on the other laptop, 4 - move the HD back into your locked laptop and boot.

Comment: I cannot know your system configurations, so I add: the HD from the other, non-locked laptop has no purpose in this, put it aside. If you have more than  one HD in either system they have no purpose, at least disconnect them so you wont accidentally install on the wrong HD. Once you install Ubuntu the CD has no more purpose, Ubuntu minimal should boot from your locked system's HD, and you could start configuring Ubuntu to fit your purpose.

Comment: Your welcome. It does not always work, but you must have picked just the right ISO, and the hardware of both of your laptop must be close [EDIT: compatible] enough. Good luck installing, and more fun using Ubuntu!